# How to Update a table from python with data in daframe

Tags: python

I have python dataframe. I have to update data into a table with data in dataframe.
how to do this using python.

Thanks
Naren

Comment: have you tried any python script to do so? if yes then please add that too

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,5))
ax.axis("off")
table1 = ax.table(cellText=data.values,colLabels=data.columns,loc='center',cellLoc='center')
# the data variable is your dataframe
```

There are additional properties you can apply to the table, you can find them on matplotlib docs
For example to change font size:

```
table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.set_fontsize(20)
```